# Need to serialize binded JSF controls in ViewScope Bean

Tags: java, serialization, jsf-2

In our `ViewScope` bean, We have to bind a `PanelGrid` to the backing bean because we dynamically add children components to that `PanelGrid` in run time according to some criteria loaded from the database. so we have to use binding, and we need to serialize the bean as a functional requirement to store it then in a NoSQL database. The problem is that JSF controls are not `Serializable`, also classes like `ELContext` and `ELResolver` are not `Serializable` either. Any idea for a workaround or even why `JSF` Controls are made non-serializable?

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont just search you PanelGrid by id at runtime and then add components? Or bind it to a request scope bean and then access that bean from you view bean?

Comment: "Why you dont just search you PanelGrid by id at runtime and then add components" In order for the added components to be displayed, I have to bind the PanelGrid to the backing bean

"Or bind it to a request scope bean and then access that bean from you view bean"
Cannot inject a request scope in a view scope, only session or application